# How to put file paths into variable in ansible?

Tags: python, linux, dictionary, ansible, yaml

I'm trying to filter paths from a file to a variable from a dictionary
the paths file:
paths.yml

```
---

 files:
         - {path: /root/files_to_copy/file_1}

 files:
         - {path: /root/files_to_copy/file_2}
         - {path: /root/files_to_copy/file_3}
         - {path: /root/files_to_copy/file_4}

 files:
         - {path: /root/files_to_copy/file_5}
         - {path: /root/files_to_copy/file_6 }
         - {path: /root/files_to_copy/file_7 }
```

what my main.yml:
why I can't use paths.values().path ?? or split ??

```
    - name: putting paths into a variable
      include_vars:
        file: paths.yml
        name: paths
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ paths.values() }}"


result: 
   ok: [192.168.1.10] => {
        "msg": [
           [
                {
                    "path": "/root/files_to_copy/file_2"
                },
                {
                    "path": "/root/files_to_copy/file_3"
                },
                {
                    "path": "/root/files_to_copy/file_4"
                }
            ],
```

I want the output something like this: /root/files_to_copy/file_2, without path and braces

Comment: Where is your Python showing what you have tried and the error or incorrect outcome you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have loaded `paths.yml` file with name `paths`, it loaded the whole file in a variable `paths` and the values are all the key value pair from `paths.yml` file.

To extract only the final `path` there are multiple options. Here is a sample:

```yaml
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ paths.values() | flatten | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - /root/files_to_copy/file_1
  - /root/files_to_copy/file_2
  - /root/files_to_copy/file_3
  - /root/files_to_copy/file_4
  - /root/files_to_copy/file_5
  - /root/files_to_copy/file_6
  - /root/files_to_copy/file_7
```

Alternative and probably simpler, using [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) filter.

```yaml
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ paths | json_query('*[].path') | list }}"
```